# R: Compare string variables with different levels

Tags: r, string, logical-operators, r-factor

can I know how to compare two string variables with different levels in R?

I would like to check is if variable Q1 is matching with in Q2 so that I can do some validation to my data in later on

```
Key  Q1      Q2               
 1   Apple   Pineapple       
 2   Banana  Banana              
 3   Apple   Papaya              
 4   Orange  ""                    
 5   Papaya  ""                 
 6   Apple   Apple
```

and have result as below

```
Key  Q1      Q2          Result           
 1   Apple   Pineapple   No   
 2   Banana  Banana      Yes           
 3   Apple   Papaya      No             
 4   Orange  ""          No                      
 5   Papaya  ""          No              
 6   Apple   Apple       Yes
```

I got an error message stated that

```
"level sets of factors are different"


$ Q1    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Apple","Banana",..: 1 2... 
$ Q2    : Factor w/ 5 levels "","Pineapple","Banana"...
```

Can anyone help with it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Convert to character and try again

Comment: @Sotos Thanks a lot. It's so simple but I'm unable to think of it. Haha

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Q1 = c("Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Papaya", "Apple")
Q2 = c("Pineapple", "Banana", "Papaya", "", "", "Apple")

df = as.data.frame(cbind(Q1, Q2))
df$Q1 = as.character(df$Q1)
df$Q2 = as.character(df$Q2)

df$Results = ifelse(df$Q1 == df$Q2, "Yes", "No")
df

> df
      Q1        Q2 Results
1  Apple Pineapple      No
2 Banana    Banana     Yes
3  Apple    Papaya      No
4 Orange                No
5 Papaya                No
6  Apple     Apple     Yes
```

Comment: Thanks. Will have a try